# Use the Object that is calling the method

Tags: java, methods, syntax

Apologies for the terribly worded question, but I'm a bit new to Java and still a bit unsure how to word my problems/ not really sure if it's possible to do what I want to.

I have a class called `ClassA` which has a trivial method `returnInt` that looks something like this:

```
public class ClassA {

private int numberino;

public ClassA(Int int) {
   this.numberino = int;

public boolean isPositive(){
   if (this.numberino > 0){
      return true;
   return false;

public int returnInt() {
   final int addVal = 2;
   int sum = 1
   sum = addVal*numberino + sum;
   return sum;

}
```

Now when I call this method in another main loop, like:

```
ClassA temp = new ClassA(7);
temp.returnInt();
```

My question is, is there anyway I can pass the object `temp` into the `returnInt()` method, so I could perhaps use the `isPositive(int)` method on it without changing the structure (by passing in an argument) of the returnInt() method?
Something like this is how I would imagine it being (but I know it's wrong);

```
public int returnInt() {
   final int addVal = 2;
   int sum = 1
   if (temp.isPositive()){
       sum = addVal*numberino + sum;
   }
   return sum;
```

Where that `temp` is Object being created and the method `returnInt()` is the method being used from it.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`returnInt` is an instance method of `ClassA`, so it can call any method of `ClassA`. There's no need to pass anything.

```
public int returnInt() {
   final int addVal = 2;
   int sum = 1
   if (isPositive()) { // or this.isPositive() if you want to be explicit
       sum = addVal*numberino + sum;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Right, that's given he is operating in a non-static context (which he is) :)

Comment: I don't see how this is a static context, the method is a instance-method and he is using another instance-method of the same instance in it.

Comment: Ah perfect. I screwed myself up overthinking the semantics of it all. Thanks!